# Data Structure for time scheduling?

Tags: sorting, data-structures

I am in need of a data structure that can properly model blocks of time, like appointments. For example, each appointment has a time it starts on, and a time it ends on. I need to have extremely fast access to things like:

- Does a specified start time and end time conflict with an existing event?
- What events exist from a specified start time and end time?

Ideally the data structure could model something like the image below.

[image]

I thought of using a binary search tree (ex. Java's `TreeMap`) but I can't think of what *key* or *value* I would use. Is there a single data structure or combination of data structures that is strong at modeling this?

Answer (score 0):

A Guava [`Table`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table) would probably work for your use case, depending on what it is you want to actually index on.

A naive approach would be to index by name, then time of day, and then have a value whether or not this particular block is occupied by that particular person.

This would make the instantiation of the object become...

```
Table<String, LocalDateTime, Boolean> calendar = TreeBasedTable.create();
```

You would populate each individual's allocation at a given interval.  You get to set what that interval is - if it's broken into 15, 30 or 1 hour periods (as defined by the table).

To find if a time is occupied, you look for the closest interval to the time you want to schedule a person.  You'd use the `column()` method for this to see if there's *any* availability, or you could get specific and get a row for the individual.  This means you'd have to pull two values; the start time you want, and however many minutes your interval is out.  That part I'll have to leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: When you say index by the time of day, do you mean the starting time, or the ending time of the event? Also keep in mind events may be like: `start: 4/23/2019 1:30, end: 12/24/2022 18:00`.

Comment: You'd keep track of time for all 24 hours in a given day.  You'd decide what the intervals are to break the periods up - 30 minutes would be fine - so you'd be storing 48 date times.  You'd store a boolean if the user was occupied during that time slot.